# XUnit Tests printing many numbers in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, unit-testing, command-line, xunit

[image]

I am running 11 unit tests with xunit framework for a .NET application. I am running with the "dotnet test" command. There are almost two thousand (2000) lines of random numbers logged as shown in the screenshot. This does not happen when I run the same command in the Command Prompt; it only happens in PowerShell. I am just curious as to what the numbers mean and/or how I can get rid of it. My tests have no code explicitly indicating that anything like this should be printed. I hope this is enough info.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what they are but you can get rid of the output by using `dotnet test | Out-Null`